# Embedded CSS not working in Gmail

Tags: css, email, gmail, html-email, email-client

According to latest Gmail doc, embedded CSS is supported: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css

However, I copy their example into a file css.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .colored {
        color: blue;
      }
      #body {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='body'>
      <p>Hi Pierce,</p>
      <p class='colored'>This text is blue.</p=>
      <p>Jerry</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And send via command line:

```
cat css.html  | mail -s "$(echo -e "Test\nContent-Type: text/html")" me@example.com
```

No matter in the Gmail web site or Gmail app, they are both not working and show as plain text. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it has not been rolled out yet.  The documentation you referenced is what will be supported once it comes out "Later this month". ([ref](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/09/your-emails-optimized-for-every-screen-with-responsive-design.html) - gmail google blog 09/14/16)

> Starting later this month, Gmail and Inbox by Gmail will support
>   emails created with responsive design, meaning their content adapts to
>   fit screens of all sizes.